# Flutter, good state management pattern for working with firebase (eg instead of chaining StreamBuilder)

Tags: firebase, flutter

What I need to do is to fetch a list of `users`, then fetch the 2nd list from collection `users_last_active` (secondary list, used to compute a field for records in `users`), and then for each user update `lastActive` field with relevant value.

Currently, I'm using the `BLOC` pattern, and combining those 2 lists following way:

```
  //* Returns the final list of profiles
  Stream<List<Profile>> get profileStream => Rx.combineLatest2(
        database.lastActiveStream()
        database.usersStream(),
        _profileCombiner, //* Map to final profile objects
      );
```

This pattern solves the problem, but I've encountered a situation when I need to pull from firebase (secondary list for computing a field) for `users` if only certain conditions uphold. And pulling all records and merging as above might be unfeasible in the long run and become a performance bottleneck. So, what I need is something like chaining 2 streams, or assigning a watcher for a widget that handles records from the `users` collection. Or, maybe even better, if there was a state management pattern/package that is targeting firebase/firestore and accounts for these types of problems. Please share your solution if you have encountered this situation, thank you!